# Generating %pc relative address of constant data

Tags: gcc, arm, fpic, relative-addressing

Is there a way to have gcc generate `%pc` relative addresses of constants?  Even when the string appears in the text segment, arm-elf-gcc will generate a constant pointer to the data, load the address of the pointer via a `%pc` relative address and then dereference it.  For a variety of reasons, I need to skip the middle step.  As an example, this simple function:

```
const char * filename(void)
{
    static const char _filename[]
            __attribute__((section(".text")))
            = "logfile";
    return _filename;
}
```

generates (when compiled with `arm-elf-gcc-4.3.2 -nostdlib -c
-O3 -W -Wall logfile.c`):

```
00000000 <filename>:
   0:   e59f0000        ldr     r0, [pc, #0]    ; 8 <filename+0x8>
   4:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
   8:   0000000c        .word   0x0000000c

0000000c <_filename.1175>:
   c:   66676f6c        .word   0x66676f6c
  10:   00656c69        .word   0x00656c69
```

I would have expected it to generate something more like:

```
filename:
    add r0, pc, #0
    bx lr
_filename.1175:
    .ascii "logfile\000"
```

The code in question needs to be partially position independent since it will be relocated in memory at load time, but also integrate with code that was not compiled `-fPIC`, so there is no global offset table.

My current work around is to call a non-inline function (which *will* be done via a `%pc` relative address) to find the offset from the compiled location in a technique similar to how `-fPIC` code works:

```
static intptr_t
__attribute__((noinline))
find_offset( void )
{
    uintptr_t pc;
    asm __volatile__ (
            "mov %0, %%pc" : "=&r"(pc)
    );

    return pc - 8 - (uintptr_t) find_offset;
}
```

But this technique requires that **all** data references be fixed up manually, so the `filename()` function in the above example would become:

```
const char * filename(void)
{
    static const char _filename[]
            __attribute__((section(".text")))
            = "logfile";
    return _filename + find_offset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, maybe you have to compile it as -fPIC to get PIC.  Or simply write it in assembler, assembler is a lot easier than the C you are writing.

```
00000000 :
   0:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 14 
   4:   e59f000c    ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; 18 
   8:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
   c:   e0830000    add r0, r3, r0
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   00000004    andeq   r0, r0, r4
  18:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

0000001c :
  1c:   66676f6c    strbtvs r6, [r7], -ip, ror #30
  20:   00656c69    rsbeq   r6, r5, r9, ror #24
```

Are you getting the same warning I am getting?

```
/tmp/ccySyaUE.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccySyaUE.s:35: Warning: ignoring changed section attributes for .text
```

Comment: Yes, I do get the same warning.  The easiest hack around it is to add a bogus newline and comment:

    __attribute__((section(".text\n#"))).

It can't be compiled with -fPIC since there are functions in ROM that are at explicit addresses.  Assembly works for me, but not for the other users of the system...